# Get on the plane, get in the car?

Tags: prepositions

I'd say "I get **in** the plane", but apparently this language tries hard not to make sense.

Comment: See [This question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/155/in-and-on-how-can-i-decide-which-one-to-use-for-vehicles/171#171) on our sister site, http://ell.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Are you asking which is the normal usage, why it is, whether alternatives are acceptable ...? Or merely griping?